# Why doesn't a deleted default constructor catch this?

Tags: c++

I noticed that declaring an instance of a class with an explicit `()` does not throw an error despite having deleted the default constructor, why is this?

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = delete;
};

int main() {
    //Foo foo; // Throws an error as expected
    Foo bar(); // Does not throw an error
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation invocation**: `g++ -std=c++14 foo.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Foo bar()` is a declaration of function, which returns `Foo` and takes no arguments.

See [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @asimes no, it's a **declaration.** Or do you see a function body there?